# Applescript cUrl Result and writing one result in a new variable

Tags: applescript

I am using applescript and would like to store only a part into a variable from the result of my CURL.

I have the following curl call

> set token to (do shell script "curl -X POST
> https://api.whatever.test/auth/signin --header 'Content-Type:
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode
> 'username=MYUSERNAME' --data-urlencode 'password=MYPASSWORD'
> --data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' --data-urlencode 'client_id=myclientid' --data-urlencode
> 'client_secret=myclientsecret'")

and get the following result:

> {
> "token_type": "bearer",
> "access_token": "d196a5e5cceb4cf4015693f07e8ea7ce6b19da6c",
> "expires_in": 3600 }

now i just want to store the tokenvalue in a new variable.

> set tokenvalue to ..........?

(here should come in now d196a5e5cceb4cf4015693f07e8ea7ce6b19da6c)

How do I do this?

Comment: If the _value_ of the `token` _variable_ was actually `{token_type:"bearer", access_token:"d196a5e5cceb4cf4015693f07e8ea7ce6b19da6c", expires_in:3600}` and not what you've shown, you could use: `set tokenvalue to access_token of token` -- That said, what you've shown won't compile.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is exactly as I wrote above. 

I have already tried with set tokenvalue to access_token of token.

is there anything I can do to somehow rebuild the result so I can use it?

Comment: If directly before the `do shell script` _command_ you use `set AppleScript's text item delimiters to quote` and then directly after the `do shell script` _command_ you use `set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}` and then `return word 4 of token` does it return e.g. `"d196a5e5cceb4cf4015693f07e8ea7ce6b19da6c"`?

Comment: Yes, then I have exactly this result.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, it is exactly as I wrote above. I have already tried with set tokenvalue to access_token of token. is there anything I can do to somehow rebuild the result so I can use it?

As you have confirmed in the comments under the OP that the *value* of `token` is indeed:

```
{ "token_type": "bearer", "access_token": "d196a5e5cceb4cf4015693f07e8ea7ce6b19da6c", "expires_in": 3600 }
```

Not:

```
{token_type:"bearer", access_token:"d196a5e5cceb4cf4015693f07e8ea7ce6b19da6c", expires_in:3600}
```

Which is not a valid **AppleScript** *record* like what's shown directly above, then using `AppleScript's text item delimiters` is one way to rework what's returned into something usable.

Note that while in the comments I had you try `return word 4 of token` I would not rely on or use it and do it in a bit more robust manner, as show in the *example* **AppleScript** *code* below. By doing it this way it provides *error handling* in that if the *value* of `token` does not contain `"access_token"` then `tokenvalue` will be `missing value` and you can test against that for additional *error handling*. It also allows for `"access_token"` to be in a different order than shown.

I'd use the following to set the *value* of `tokenvalue` to e.g.: `d196a5e5cceb4cf4015693f07e8ea7ce6b19da6c`

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to quote
set token to (do shell script "curl -X POST https://api.whatever.test/auth/signin --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'username=MYUSERNAME' --data-urlencode 'password=MYPASSWORD' --data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' --data-urlencode 'client_id=myclientid' --data-urlencode 'client_secret=myclientsecret'")
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}

set tokenvalue to missing value
repeat with i from 1 to the length of words of token
    if word i of token is "access_token" then
        set tokenvalue to word (i + 1) of token
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat

return tokenvalue
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated per comment

You could use sed to extract the desired value. This searches for `"access_token":`  followed by a 40-character alphanumeric.

`sed -E 's|.*"access_token": "([[:alnum:]]{40})".*|\1|g'`

This is illustrated using the clipboard to simulate your curl result:

```
set token to do shell script "echo '{ \"token_type\": \"bearer\", \"access_token\": \"d196a5e5cceb4cf4015693f07e8ea7ce6b19da6c\", \"expires_in\": 3600 }'"
--> "{ \"token_type\": \"bearer\", \"access_token\": \"d196a5e5cceb4cf4015693f07e8ea7ce6b19da6c\", \"expires_in\": 3600 }"

set the clipboard to token
--> { "token_type": "bearer", "access_token": "d196a5e5cceb4cf4015693f07e8ea7ce6b19da6c", "expires_in": 3600 }
```

Then pipe that through sed:

```
set tokenvalue to do shell script "pbpaste | sed -E 's|.*\"access_token\": \"([[:alnum:]]{40})\".*|\\1|'"
--> "d196a5e5cceb4cf4015693f07e8ea7ce6b19da6c"
```

You could likely just pipe your curl output through sed but you may need to tweak sed as the shell may automatically strip out some characters (e.g. quotes and spaces).

NB I used `[:alnum:]` but `a-z0-9` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 -- NOTE: uncomment 1st code line and comment 2nd code line to test with CURL
-- set token to (do shell script "curl -X POST https://api.whatever.test/auth/signin --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'username=MYUSERNAME' --data-urlencode 'password=MYPASSWORD' --data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' --data-urlencode 'client_id=myclientid' --data-urlencode 'client_secret=myclientsecret'")
set token to "{ \"token_type\": \"bearer\", \"access_token\": \"d196a5e5cceb4cf4015693f07e8ea7ce6b19da6c\", \"expires_in\": 3600 }"

set tokenvalue to {token_type:"", access_token:"", expires_in:""}

set {ATID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, {}}
tell tokenvalue
    set its token_type to token's word 2
    set its access_token to token's word 4
    set its expires_in to (token's word 6) as integer
end tell
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ATID

return tokenvalue
--> {token_type:"bearer", access_token:"d196a5e5cceb4cf4015693f07e8ea7ce6b19da6c", expires_in:3600}
```